# Закрытие окна при клике на изображение

Tags: c++, qt

В окне есть несколько изображений. При нажатии на каждое из них должно происходить то или иное событие. К примеру, закрытие текущего окна. Я попытался реализовать это через встраивание виджета, который отрисовывает картинку, в QGraphicsScene и последующим подсоединением слота close() к сигналу clicked(), но у меня ничего не выходит. Подскажите, как можно реализовать такую задачу.

qpaintwidget.h

```
#ifndef QPAINTWIDGET_H
#define QPAINTWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class QPaintEvent;

class QPaintWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QPaintWidget(QWidget * parent = 0);
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
signals:
    void clicked();
};

#endif // QPAINTWIDGET_H
```

qpaintwidget.cpp

```
#include "qpaintwidget.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QImage>

QPaintWidget::QPaintWidget(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
}

void QPaintWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
    QPainter p(this);
    QImage image(":/Ресурсы/red.png");
    QRect target(50,50, 40, 40);
    QRect source(0, 0, 40, 40);
    p.drawImage(target, image, source);
}
```

diag.cpp

```
ui->setupUi(this);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    view->setScene(scene);

    view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    view->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    wgt = new QPaintWidget;
    wgt->resize(100,100);
    QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = scene->addWidget(wgt);

    connect(wgt, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));

    view->show();
```

Comment: А где отправляется сигнал `clicked`? Я думаю здесь проще поступить через `installEventFilter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QWidget не имеет сигнала clicked()
Чтобы отслеживать клики, необходимо установить eventfilter:

mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
....
private:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
....
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
....
// эвентфильтр на чилдренов не распространяется, поэтому установим его для нужного виджета:
ui->someWidget->installEventFilter(this); 
}
....
// И собственно сам обработчик событий
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){

    if(obj==ui->someWidget){  // Проверяем что событие от нужного виджета 
      if(event->type()==QEvent::MouseButtonPress){ // проверяем тип события
        qApp->quit();
      }
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Comment: Позволил себе исправить опечатку.